# Color picker for jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, color-picker

There are so many color picker for jQuery but when I try to implement them in normal jQuery Mobile they don't work as expected. They do conflict with the jQuery Mobile framework and render as they want.

Is there any other jQuery colorpickers that is compatible with jQuery Mobile??

Please advice me.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you seen this, may be this can help you

https://github.com/Gautier/jquery-colorpicker-mobile

http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/

Answer (score 1):

Give `<input type="color">` a try. It might be fitting for what you are after.

If you are looking for something consistent across browsers/platforms, [this](https://mobiscroll.com/color-picker) preset based mobile picker could help. Single and multiple select with the option of luminosity refinement. View [examples](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/color).